# How can I encrypt the home directory with active directory user credentials

Tags: 14.04, encryption, active-directory

We are evaluating how Ubuntu Desktops will suit our development environment. But we can't find a way to encrypt home directory with active directory(AD) user credentials.

- All the users are places in AD
- Users Home directory is Ubuntu desktop under /home/<1st name.2nd name@EXAMPLE.COM>/

We are able to login to Ubuntu desktop with AD user credentials.

if we try to encrypt the users home directory using :

```
sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u <1st name.2nd name@EXAMPLE.COM>
```

Return an error :

```
ERROR:  Cannot find the home directory of <1st name.2nd name@EXAMPLE.COM>.
```

Can anyone help us to overcome this issue

Comment: AD as in active directory?

Comment: yes. AD --> Active Directory

Comment: As far as I know, AD is purely microsoft technology and only works on windows. However, you might be able to get the AD database of users and their password and use their credentials in Ubuntu while encrypting their home folders. This websites shows a way to encrypt: http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/

Comment: This question might gain more traction on http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank for that I have tried this, As per my understanding, if we use AD authentication to login to linux, system not keep that user as system user. eg: if we check AD user in /etc/passwd it wan't show. If i run sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u <AD.user> system will give error ERROR:  Cannot find the home directory of userxyz@EXAMPLE.COM

Comment: You might find [this informative](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/encrypting-files-in-a-windows-environment/3152#3152)

Comment: May I be so bold as to ask you to [edit] into your question  why you wish to encrypt users home directories? and Where do these directories reside? A Windows server or an Ubuntu server or something else?